# KnockoutJS Currency Binding with Real-time Updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In a recent Knockout interface I've been building, I've attempted to set up auto save. It's designed so that saves occur 1 second after you stop making changes.

Here's the problem. By default, KO relies on the blur event on inputs to update the viewModel. My interface doesn't save the data if you leave the page or refresh your browser before clicking out of the box.

To solve this, I've enabled `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`, which works for all string inputs. However, I have a numeric PricePerLF field that is extended so that it always contains a numeric value. I used the suggested extender found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};
```

How would I make this numeric extender play nice with `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`? It'd also be nice to force it to display a certain number of decimal points such as `2.80` instead of `2.8`.

Comment: I'm confused. valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' should work fine, even with your numeric extender. It's not?

Comment: It makes it difficult to enter decimals...

Comment: I just tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TtPAx/ My question is, how do you want it to behave? It's not clear from your question how you want it to behave.

Comment: Judah - I need to be able to type the following: '', '.22', '0.11', '1.23'. Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: Does the posted answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I made this extender a while back, tried it with afterkeydown and it works decent, if you use decimal format it works less perfect

http://jsfiddle.net/yEgmT/1/

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(observable, format) {
    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {  
            return Globalize.format(observable(), format === true ? undefined : format);
        },
        write: function(value) {           
            if(value.substring) {
                value = Globalize.parseFloat(value)
            }                    
            if(!isNaN(value)) {
                observable(value);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This almost works. However, the numbers get cut off after the 4 decimal place. Try "0.2693". Also, is there a way to not introduce a dependency on Globalize? Thanks!

Comment: Strange works here (FF, IE), just a note I based it on an old fiddle of mine so Globalize is set to Swedish culture, which uses comma not dot as seperator. I dont have chrome installed on this machine and I rember there was a bug in Globallize, try to explicit set the format change to .extend({format: "N"});